# How to take any numbers of digits after decimal and in which data type I have to store

Tags: javascript

I want to take any number of digits after decimal. 
For Eg:

```
String pay = "2000.000000";
```

Output : Payable Amount is = 2000.0 if it in float

```
String pay = "2000.000000";
```

Output : Payable Amount is = 2000.0 if it is in double

What should I do take all the digits after decimal

Answer (score 1):

Try [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
2000.000000.toFixed(2); // 2000.00
```

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it in javascript. If it does not work for you, please tell us what you tried to use this command, so we can help you out. Compare here: http://jsfiddle.net/ex0mgcau/

Comment: Ok....The Problem is I am taking 2000.000000 in one String Variable (bocz its coming somewhere in type String) then I have to convert this whole String in one specific dataType without loosing any of the digits after decimal. So that I can use it in my further calculations. Can u plz give me proper solution ifu have....??

Comment: @Sourabh pls edit your guestion to include the fact that you need to convert the value from a string first.

Comment: String payamount = "2000.000000"                               float payableamt = Float.parseFloat(payamount);
System.out.println("Payable Amount is = "+ payableamt);              I want all digits after decimal and store it in variable for maths calculations

Answer (score 1):

You can alternatively use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function of JS.

```
parseFloat("2000.0000").toFixed(2) //=> 2000.00
parseFloat("2000.1000").toFixed(2) //=> 2000.10
parseFloat("2000.0200").toFixed(2) //=> 2000.02
```